FluentD file type buffer path
I have my old fluentd config in which I have a <match> type copy then having two <scope> one is a type forward to a server with a <buffer> and the second is prometheus type for metrics. It is working very well and I have no issue. In the buffer tag of the first <scope> there is no path property
I am looking to add a http type <scope> for the same config. The <buffer> is configured the same with retries, flush properties and all and no path property in the <buffer>.
When executing fluentD i have the error message saying  error_class=Fluent::ConfigError error=\"buffer path is not configured. specify 'path'in <buffer>\""}
Which I know it is related to my new <scope> but what i am not understanding is why my new <scope> with the same exact <buffer> required a path property but not my previous <scope> ? Is there something in HTTP <scope> vs Forward type <scope> that is different and I am missing ?
I cannot really provide my exact config because of confidentiality reasons
Thanks
